# Path security in Spring Security 5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Using org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server5.1.0.RC2 (via org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.1.0.M3) I'm trying to enable security for some http paths, but disable it for others, using JWT based token security.

I tried the following, but its inconsistently enforcing security on various paths and http methods:

- Enforced on GET /accounts?name=Checking
- Enforced on POST /accounts
- Not enforced on GET /customers?name=John
- Enforced on POST /customers

Why would it enforce on the POST to /customers?

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/customers").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/customers/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/accounts/**").authenticated()
                .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt().jwtDecoder(this.jwtDecoder);
        // @formatter:on

        return http.build();
   }

}
```

Comment: I partially solved this.

Answer (score 1):

I partially solved this via two things:

1. Added csrf().disable() (maybe this is ok since these are stateless REST services?)
2. Before I was sending an authorization header on the requests where I mentioned auth was being enforced.  I thought it would have skipped authorization, even with the header, but it processed it anyway.

Updated code:

```
    @Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    // @formatter:off
    http
        .csrf()
            .disable()
        .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/customers/**").permitAll()
            .and()
        .authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/accounts/**").authenticated()
            .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt().jwtDecoder(this.jwtDecoder);

    return http.build();
}
```